# Using a NPM module with global variables in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, web-component

I'm trying to use the [exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) in a webpack+babeljs project. This library (exif-js) creates a global variable "EXIF", but I can't access it in Chrome devtools neither in my js script.

I tried to use webpack provide-plugin to make "EXIF" visible in all pages, but it is not working.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      EXIF: 'exif-js/exif.js'
    })
]
```

What is the best way to use this library in a webpack project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in CommonJS, it exports the `EXIF` var instead of attaching it to the global scope.

Which means with webpack you can just import it like any other module:

`var exif = require('exif-js');`

To demonstrate, see [this webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KizeQcKSu3k4rCeMsol)

If you actually do need it in global scope, you can manually attach it to the `window` object after importing it:

```
var exif = require('exif-js');
window.EXIF = exif;
```

To answer the actual title of the question regarding using scripts that set global variables, you can usually either use `ProvidePlugin` as you demonstrated, or you can use [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/):

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's environment. This feature is typically most useful to library developers, however there are a variety of applications for it.

For example (in your `webpack.config.js`):

```
externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

However, this works differently than `ProvidePlugin`. Whereas `ProvidePlugin` resolves undeclared variables that are assumed to be global, `externals` resolves specific module names to global variables that are assumed to exist (eg: `require('jquery')` would resolve to `window.$`).

Comment: How exactly did you do it @BrunoSoares I can't seem to make it work ...